# How to adjust PdfPTable inside PdfPCell in iTextPdf?

Tags: spring-mvc, itext

I want to make a form using PdfPTable like below :

[image]

How to adjust PdfPTable inside PdfPCell in iTextPdf ?

I have tried using following code without success :

```
    Orders listOrders = (Orders) model.get("listOrders");

    PdfContentByte pdfContentByte = writer.getDirectContent();

    Barcode128 barcode128 = new Barcode128();
    barcode128.setCodeType(Barcode128.CODE128);
    barcode128.setCode(listOrders.getGenerated_orderID());
    Image codeEANImage = barcode128.createImageWithBarcode(pdfContentByte, null, null);
    codeEANImage.scalePercent(100);

    Font font = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA);
    font.setColor(BaseColor.BLACK);
    font.setSize(8);

    Image image = Image.getInstance(logo);

    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("some text",font);
    paragraph.setAlignment(ALIGN_CENTER);
    document.add(paragraph);

    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
    table.setWidthPercentage(80);
    table.setWidths(new int[]{1, 1, 1});

    PdfPCell pdfPCell = new PdfPCell();
    pdfPCell.setImage(image);

    image.scalePercent(10);
    table.addCell(pdfPCell);


    table.addCell(codeEANImage);
    table.addCell(listOrders.getSender_address());

    PdfPTable tableLeft = new PdfPTable(2);
    tableLeft.setWidthPercentage(40);
    tableLeft.setWidths(new int[]{1, 1});
    tableLeft.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);

    PdfPCell leftLabel = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Sender",font));
    leftLabel.setColspan(2);

    tableLeft.addCell(leftLabel);

    tableLeft.addCell(new Phrase("Person:",font));
    tableLeft.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(listOrders.getPersonality(),font))).setBorder(Rectangle.BOX);

    PdfPTable tableRight = new PdfPTable(2);
    tableRight.setWidthPercentage(40);
    tableRight.setWidths(new int[]{1, 1});
    tableRight.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);

    PdfPCell rightLabel = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Rec:",font));
    rightLabel.setColspan(2);

    tableRight.addCell(rightLabel);

    tableRight.addCell(new Phrase("Name:",font));
    tableRight.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(listOrders.getReceiver_firstname(),font))).setBorder(Rectangle.BOX);

    table.addCell(tableLeft);
    table.addCell(tableRight);
    table.setSpacingBefore(0);

    document.add(table);
```

Could anybody suggest me how to construct the same ?

Comment: I did it, but i have a problem with a head cell, logo barcode and text are not the same row, what should I do?

Comment: It works now, I fixed my error)) thanks

Comment: If you've fixed it yourself, would it be possible to detail how you've done it in an answer to the question? That way, people who encounter the same problem will find how to fix the problem instead of just your remark that you did fix it?